# How to use assert_raise to test for an error in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing, assert, factorial

I have the programs `factorial.rb` and `test_factorial.rb`. The former looks like this:

```
def factorial(n)
  (1..n).inject(:*) || 1
end
```

`test_factorial` looks like this:

```
def test_number
  assert_equal 6, factorial(3),"3! should be 6"
end

def test_zero
  assert_equal 1, factorial(0), "0! should be 1"
end
```

I need to add another method, `test_negative` to the test file that confirms an error is raised when the factorial is negative. I looked at the documentation but still don't understand what I'm supposed to do. Do I have to specify a certain type of error after `assert_raise`? Do I need to add code to `factorial.rb` or not since the error is generated automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you are using minitest, if you are trying to test that an error is raised you can use the `asert_raises` method. (Notice the plural form)

```
def test_negative
  assert_raises <expected error name> do
    factorial(-1)
  end
end
```

However, no error will be raised with the example you presented so far.

Additional information:

- This example `(1..-5).inject(:*)` will evaluate to nil. You will not get an error. I assume your `test_negative` should assert that the return value is `1` given your current implementation.
- Also if you would like to give inject a default value you can pass it as the first argument: `(1..n).inject(1, :*)`. This way you avoid using the `||` operator.

A great suggestion from @ArupRakshit below is to raise your own `NegativeFactorial` exception. You will need to define it first.

```
class NegativeFactorial < StandardError; end
```

Then you can use it in your factorial method like this:

```
def factorial(n)
  raise NegativeFactorial, "The number provided is negative." if n < 0
  (1..n).inject(1, :*)
end
```

And you can implement your `test_negative` to assert that the exception has been raised.

```
def test_negative
  assert_raises NegativeFactorial do
    factorial(-1)
  end
end
```

Comment: The OP could do `raise NegativeFactorial if n <0`...inside the method.

Comment: How do I assert that the exception has been raised? That's what I'm having trouble with.

Comment: @N1ghtshade3 I've updated my answer to include the test that uses assert_raises. Your current implementation __does not__ raise any errors if you provide a numerical character. The answer includes a way to raise an error and a way to rescue that error.